# Intellij Plugin Development bundling dependencies

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am creating an Intellij plugin that will require another plugin and some libraries that will automatically be added to new projects of a specific type. I can't find anywhere how to bundle these plugins with my plugin. I need help figuring out how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't bundle another plugin with your plugin. All you can do is specify a `<depends>` tag which will require your users to install the other plugin. If the other plugin is available in the plugin repository, IntelliJ IDEA should offer to install it automatically.

To bundle libraries, simply add them as dependencies to your plugin, and they will be packaged and distributed in the `lib` subdirectory of the plugin installation directory.

Comment: My problem is that the package is not in the plugin repository

Comment: Then your only option is to build your own code to download the plugin, place it into the plugins directory of IntelliJ IDEA and restart the IDE.